# Locating aggregated svf models properly

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

In order to show several svf models converted from revit files the following code is used and it works:

```
const modelFileUrls = 
[{
    modelId: 9,
    url: "{url}/Resource/3D view/BIM360 1746305/BIM360.svf",
    globalOffset: {
    x: 3701854.1994750663,
    y: 3001199.973753281,
    z: 0  
  }
},
{
    modelId: 10,
    url: "{url}/Resource/3D view/3D/3D.svf",
    globalOffset: {
    x: 3701853.805774279,
    y: 3001199.973753281,
    z: 0
  }
}]

const div = document.getElementById("forge-viewer")
let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(div, config3d)
viewer.initialize()

// Models loading
modelFileUrls.forEach(model => {
    viewer.loadModel(
        model.url, {
            loadAsHidden: false,
            keepCurrentModels: true,
            globalOffset: model.globalOffset,
            applyRefPoint: true,
            isAEC: true
        }
    )
})
```

Parameter 'globalOffset' was taken from AEC.json.

The problem is to locate models properly in the shared area. I mean, how can I arrange building of one construction queue properly to set revit coorditates 'N/S', 'E/W', 'Angle to True North' for each? Now models appeare with no rotation and the position is wrong.
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the [aggregated view](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7)? Would that be an option for you? If not, another thing you could try is placing your models with a custom _xform_, not just an offset. See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher for more info.

Comment: Thanks @PetrBroz, by the way your vscode forge extention is awesome and very useful tool. As I understand in order to use Aggregated View I need to use `urn` and `AutodeskProduction` option but I need to load local svf models. Is it possible in that case of using?

Comment: Oh ok, I'm afraid the `AggregatedView` class only supports loading models from an actual Model Derivative manifest... so you would have to either (a) try mocking up a manifest that points to your custom-hosted SVFs, or (b) stick the the code you have now and control the placement using an `THREE.Matrix4` transform and not just the offset.

Comment: If I choose (a), does it mean that all urn properties in derivative manifest json, e.g. `urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:{base64stringUrn}/output/Resource/3D view/Navisworks 243345/Navisworks.svf`, must be converted to `{https://mycustomhost.com}/output/Resource/3D view/Navisworks 243345/Navisworks.svf`?